# Como pedir permissões para acessar o sdcard no Android 6+?

Tags: java, android, android-permission

Tenho um app que acessa o sdcard, estava tudo funcionando perfeitamente, mas notei que o Android 6 tem  um sistema de permissões onde o usuário tem que aceitar a permissão não quando o aplicativo é baixado e sim quando ela é executada!

O problema é que meu app da erro quando ele tenta acessar o sdcard em usuários com Android 6, pois ele não tem permissão, mesmo com o manifeste ok... É somente possível acessar se o usuário abrir os detalhes do App, ir em permissões e aceitar as permissões para leitura e escrita do sdcard.

Notei que muitos apps quando executam algo que precisa de permissão, mostram um dialog padrão para o usuário "aceitar ou negar a permissão X", como fazer isso? E como não aceitar que o usuário recuse essa permissão? Pois ela é praticamente a alma do app, não da para usar o app sem ela

Comment: De uma olhada nesse link http://ricardolecheta.com.br/?p=560.<br>Ele esta explicando bem facil.

Comment: A pagina oficial do android também possui um ótimo tutorial de como utilizar o novo formato http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html